# Python Dateutil parse() parameters

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am fairly new to `Python` and apologize in advance if this is a dumb question!

I am trying to use the `parse()` function to normalize the date and time I am receiving from some XMPP timestamps.

```
t1 = parse("20141126T03:44:18")
print t1
```

If I pass a string to parse as illustrated above, `parse()` behaves as expected. If I pass another function to `parse()` it fails to run with the following error:

```
    t1 = parse(msg.getTimestamp())
    print t1
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `parse` function per se, there is something wrong with your `msg.getTimestamp()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I run the following `msg.getTimestamp()` works properly:
`t1 = msg.getTimestamp()
print t1`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to do the following:
`stamp = str(msg.getTimestamp())
 t1 = parse(stamp)
 print t1`